# How to create a JSON array using PHP

Tags: php, json, format

My JSON data looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "email":"test@test.com",
        "firstName":"test",
        "lastName":"test",
        "value":"test@test.com",
        "tokens":"test@test.com"
    },
    {
        ...
    }
]
```

and php data to create json file looks like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('connection.php');
    $userId = $_SESSION['sess_user_id'];
    $act = $_POST['action'];
    $sth = mysql_query("SELECT email, firstName, lastName, email AS value, email AS tokens FROM User");
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth))
    {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    $fp = fopen('./test.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($rows));
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

When a user is added to the database, it runs this php code:

```
$file = './test.json';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
$newdata = array('email'=>$email, 'firstName' => $firstName, 'lastName'=>$lastName, 'value'=>$email, 'tokens'=>$email);
$data[] = $newdata;
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($data));
```

I want the my JSON file to look like this:

```
[
    {
        "email":"test@test.com",
        "firstName":"test",
        "lastName":"test",
        "value":"test@test.com",
        "tokens":[
            "test@test.com"
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried to figure this out, but I couldn't. Please help?

Comment: Why? `[]` means "array," and it doesn't _look_ like `email` will have >1 value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php handles arrays different than javascript (which differentiates between objects and arrays).

```
$newdata = array(
    'email'=>$email, 
    'firstName' => $firstName, 
    'lastName'=>$lastName, 
    'value'=>$email, 
    'tokens'=>array($email)
);
```

should do it.